# Using arrays which has empty items in array that are not set as null or false

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible for this array type to work? I have many fields and I would prefer if I could skip placing `false` or `null` instead of empty field. I got this list from CSV file and I only need to use this array once. Currently I get

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')
```

If it is not possible any suggestion on how to replace empty fields to null are welcome :)

```
$array = array(
array('apples','bananas','figs',,,'apples2'),
array('lemon',,'bananas3','figs2','apples3',,'apples3'),
array('apples',,,'bananas','figs',,,,'apples2'),
...
);


foreach($array as $post) {
    // something once
}
```

Comment: How about empty string `'','','',...`?

Comment: In that case I could just better replace it with false or null, but I don't know easy way to replace that, thats why I'm asking :)

Comment: Who is writing this invalid PHP code for you? A script, another person? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that it should solve the problem (it may give you NOTICE error but don't pay attention):

```
$str = "array(
array('apples','bananas','figs',,,'apples2'),
array('lemon',,'bananas3','figs2','apples3',,'apples3'),
array('apples',,,'bananas','figs',,,,'apples2')
);";

function convert_to_right_array($str) {
    $points = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        if ($str[$i] == ',' && $str[$i+1] == ',') {
            $point = [$i, $i + 1];
            $points[] = $point;
        }
    }
    $newStr = '';
    $startChar = 0;
    foreach ($points as $point) {
        $part = substr($str, $startChar, $point[0] - $startChar);
        $part = ($part[strlen($part) - 1] == ',' ? $part : $part . ',' );
        $newStr .= $part;
        $newStr .= 'null';
        $startChar = $point[1];
    }
    $newStr .= substr($str, $startChar, strlen($str));
    return $newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an array with "gaps" in the numeric key sequence:

```
<?php
$array = [
  ['apples','bananas','figs',5=>'apples2'],
  ['lemon',2=>'bananas3','figs2','apples3',6=>'apples3'],
  ['apples',3=>'bananas','figs',8=>'apples2'],
  //...
];
print_r($array);
```

But that is something different than assigning an empty or falsey value to some keys. Also it is not "faster" and probably harder to read, so questionable. Only do this if you want explicit "gaps" in the key sequence. If you want "empty" values, then code them in an explicit manner.

The output of above lines is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apples
            [1] => bananas
            [2] => figs
            [5] => apples2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lemon
            [2] => bananas3
            [3] => figs2
            [4] => apples3
            [6] => apples3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => apples
            [3] => bananas
            [4] => figs
            [8] => apples2
        )

)
```